# Pandas are stubborn to install

Tags: python, macos, gcc, pandas

I have been trying for 1-2 hours to install `pandas`.

tried:
`sudo easy_install pandas`,
`sudo pip install pandas`

manually:
`python setup.py build`,
`python setup.py install`

Now when I `pip list` I get for that module:

```
Error when trying to get requirement for VCS system Command /usr/local/bin/git config remote.origin.url failed with error code 1 in /Users/Diolor, falling back to uneditable format
Could not determine repository location of /Users/Diolor
pandas (0.12.0)
```

And of course:

```
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

I run OS X 10.8 which is notorious for the gcc compatibilities (or at least I'm unlucky).
I have installed gcc in xcode. Also:

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

Pytz, numpy and scipy can be successfully imported.

Comment: Are you using the system Python or something else? How did the installation of NumPy go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any particular reason not to use [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) distribution?

Comment: +1 for Anaconda (I have had success with Windows 7, 64-bit & Ubuntu)

Comment: herrfz: Yeah, one: didn't know it. :)